# validating multiple controls in javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am adding multiple controls on an .aspx page from the .vb page based on certain conditions.

My code looks like following:

```
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder

    sb.Append("<table border='0'cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='50%' class ='tabledata' id='tblContent'>")
    For Each item As myObject In myLst            
        sb.Append("<tr><td style='width:50%;' valign='top'>")
        sb.Append("<textarea id=txt_comments" & i & " name='txt_comments' rows='5' cols='60'></textarea></td>")
        sb.Append("<td style='width:15%' valign='top' align='center'><select ID = validate" & i & " name=ValidateValues style ='border:1;width:150px'><option value = ''>Select</option><option value = 'Yes'>Yes</option><option value = 'No'>No</option><br /><br /></td>")
                    sb.Append("</tr><tr>")
    Next
    sb.Append("</table>")
    myContent.InnerHtml = sb.ToString
```

So here I am creating  `<textarea>` and `<select>` dynamically and adding them to my div(myContent)

```
 <div id="structuredContent" runat="server">
 </div>
```

I have a button next where I need to validate for few conditions.

My validation rule is:

- User has to select either yes or no from the dropdown(`<select>`)
- If user select 'yes', they have to enter text in
  `<textarea>`(minimum1 character, maximum 1000 characters)
- If user select 'No', `<textarea>` should be disabled.

I am trying to validate like following:

```
function validateComments() {           
        var errorcheck = 0;
         $("[id^=txt_comments]").each(function () {
            var comment = $.trim($(this).val());
            $("[id^=validate]").each(function () {
                debugger;
                var value = $(this).val();

                if (comment == 0 && value == "Yes") {
                    debugger;
                    errorcheck = 1;
                }


            });


        });            if (errorcheck == 1) {
             //show error message
            }
        else {
            ErrorHide();
            return true;
        }

    }
```

I am able to validate only for one control(which is textarea) from the above code.

The textbox and respective dropdown should be validated along.

How do I add validation for dropdown and can I combine with in the same function.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't use an id (which selector would rather be #txt_comments), but use a defining classname

Comment: was the answer given now not up to your expectations? In how far was it not a help to you? As far as I can see it's a valid attempt in giving you insight how to do it, upon which you can build

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how do you expect this like `if (comment == 0) {` to work.

You'll always get a string as a value and checking it with `0` would always return false. Rather you need to check it with `""`.

And to enable/disable `textarea` you'll have to attach an event to `select` tag and do whatever you want to do.

here is an example

```js
$("#d").change(function(){
   if($(this).val() === 'n'){
     $("#t").prop('disabled', 'disabled')
   }else{
    $("#t").prop('disabled', false)
   }

});
$('body').on('click', '#b', function() {
   var text = $.trim($("#t").val());
    if(text === "" && !$("#t").prop('disabled')){
     alert("yo! not valid") 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="d">
 <option value="0">Select</option>
 <option value="y">Yes</option>
 <option value="n">No</option>
</select>
<textarea maxlength="50" id="t"></textarea>\

<button id="b">Validate</button>
```

Comment: don't you see the alert ?

Comment: This doesn't work if the dropdown has 'Select' as the first value

Comment: @Santosh this is giving you an idea on how to put things on track. Anyways, I'll update that for you :)

Comment: And I am adding the controls dynamically from .vb file. So I have to validate dynamically

Comment: `$('body').on('click', '#b', function() {` this is way to check events on dynamically added elements. you can modify for `select` with this

Comment: @GeorgeBailey I checked your updated answer. It doesn't work if I enter something in text and click validate(with out selecting the dropdown value)

Comment: so what ? if user has not selected b/w yes and no you can take it as yes coz he has not selected no. Morever, it should not take you much to modify to whatever you want

Comment: No, validation rule is User has to select anyone from the dropdown.